# Why can I do "[:]" in a numpy array as many times as I want?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I thought that I understood how numpy array works, until, by mistake a I did something like

```
x = np.array([2,3,1,0])
x[:][:]
```

and I got the same result as `x[:]` and the same as `x[:][:][:]` And now I wonder how is this possible if x is 1-D array!

I don't know if it is too basic or I'm missing something. Thanks.

Comment: There is a difference between `x[:,:]` and `x[:][:]`, `x[:][:]` is equivalent to `(x[:])[:]`. The `x[:]` will just return a view on `x`, so `x[:] == x`.

Comment: Because an interval of an interval is again an interval.

Comment: What did you expect?  Did you compare `x` and `x[:]`?  What's different, or the same?

Comment: What do you expect to happen instead?

Comment: @hpaulj It was a mistake, so I guess I expected x[:]

Comment: With Python lists `x[:]` makes a copy, a new list with the same pointers.  With arrays, it's a `view`, a new array, but with the same data buffer and attributes.  It's like you sliced the whole range of values.

Answer (score 4):

The expression `x[:][:]`, is short for `(x[:])[:]`. If you write `x[:]`, then you generate a "view" on the array `x`, this view takes all elements into account of `x`, and thus is a numpy array with exactly the same shape.

Although `x[:]` and `x` are different objects, these thus contain the same data, and in the same shape. By calling `(x[:])[:]`, you thus create another view. Numpy will see that `x[:]` is a view on `x`, and thus make another view *on `x`*, but this is thus again a view. You thus can repeat the same "trick" an arbitrary number of times.

Comment: Small technicality: `(x[:])[:]` does not create a "view on a view". It creates another view on `x`.